# How to add a git repro project as a dependency for another project

Tags: git, maven, dependencies, pom.xml

I have a git maven java project, let's call it proj1 and I want to start working on another project, proj2 also maven and java, that I want to use some methods of proj1. Proj1 may receive updates. The thing is those projects don't have a release version. They have just commit/push and are running from Jenkins.

I know it is possible to add something in pom.xml of proj2 to make the proj1 git as a dependency, but I don't know how and searched on the internet but could not find what I want. Maybe I overlooked something.

I found this tutorial, but it says about local projects, I need to do something like this but with git links, if it is possible. http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-add-a-project-as-a-dependency-of-another-project.html?page=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maven dependencies need to be artifacts from Maven repositories.

You cannot reference another git repository as dependency. You need to build the code in the git repository and deploy it to a Maven repository. Then you can reference the built artifact from the other git project.

Dependencies always work as GAV (groupId, artifactId, version), not files or git repositories.

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy your project to github package when committing. With that you can sutomatically synchonize your deployment with the github repo.

You can also set up a github repository as a maven repository.

Another possibiöity is to upload it to maven central.